# How to set the name of BLE peripheral in iOS using Core Bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I would like to write to the peripheral's name.

As I understand from the Core Bluetooth documentation, the peripheral's "name" property is readonly.

However, if the peripheral broadcasts its name (in my case the UUID of 0x2A00), is it possible for me to write to this characteristic and successfully change the name?

Comment: Only if the device has some writable property to do so. All devices don't allow renaming.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can change name of peripheral name. The require is CBCharacteristic  0x2A00(Device Name) property is available. If 0x2A00 property not available in CBCharacteristic then not possible to update name of peripheral via iOS or Android application.